# Wordpress preprocess_comment hook not firing

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a comment form on my wordpress website and I am trying to get the following to happen:

1) on the click of post comment get the data
2) if the required field is set to yes, send email

For some reason it is not working, here is my code:

```
function preprocess_comment_handler( $commentdata ) {

    mail('mail@example.com','subject','message');

   if ($commentdata['signuptomailinglistcommentform'] == "Yes") {
       mail('mail@example.com','subject','message');
   }

//some code
//return $commentdata;
}
add_filter( 'preprocess_comment' , 'preprocess_comment_handler' );
```

I even added **mail('mail@example.com','subject','message');** above the if function so that it should just run the moment I the hook is called yet there is still nothing :/

any ideas?